# socialengine: how to migrate SE3 plugins to SE4?

Tags: socialengine

I was purchased a socialengine plugin to manage my subscription plans named 'plugin subscription' and this plugin only supports SocialEngine v3+.

now i need to use the same plugin with my another social engine v4 site.how can i migrate the plugin which supports social engine 3 to socialengine 4.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, you cant easy migrate from 3 to 4. Try to find SE4 version of this plugin, this is common way.